# How to Calculate entropy of specific state?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, states-of-matter

What is the numeric value of entropy for ammonia with pressure p=20kPa and temperature T=-20ºC? 
I believe to be in reference to the thermodynamic tables and change of entropy states but can not grasp which.

Comment: Use the ideal gas law and the Sackur-Tetrode equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sackur%E2%80%93Tetrode_equation).

Comment: @probably_someone Is this an ideal gas under such conditions? And what is the contribution from rotations?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the volume of the gas or number of moles. Also, it can not be considered an ideal gas. I tried considering it and the answer that I got was 7.054kJ/kgK and the correct answer is 7.535kJ/kgK for the specific entropy.

Comment: What are you taking as the reference state of zero entropy.

Comment: I finally got it, it as really a reference issue. My mistake was not checking WolframAlpha's reference for entropy. After that, everything checked out. Actually, we can consider it to be in a state of ideal gas and use the equations for it.

Answer (score 1):

Considering it an ideal gas and a constant $c_{p}$ value. We can use the equation:
$$s_{2}-s_{1} = \int_{1}^{2}c_{p}\frac{dT}{T} - Rln(\frac{p_{2}}{p_{1}})$$
when trying to find for the same temperature as the thermodynamic table at $T=-20ºC$ 
($s_{1}=6.6073$) we get:
$$s_{2}-s_{1} =  - Rln(\frac{p_{2}}{p_{1}})$$
remembering that we have the state $p_{1}=50kPa$ ont he table and we need for $p_{2}=20kPa$, which results on the entropy value of:
$$s_{2}=7.054\frac{kJ}{kgK}$$